# WPF DataGrid focused row in the middle of visible

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to implement scrolling to specific item in a Datagrid.
fx I Choose row Nr 355, it need to scrolled to the **center** of visible grid area.

so far I the following Code for *SelectionChanged event*:

```
   private void CoreServiceLogDataGridOnSelectionChanged(
        object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs selectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if (CoreServiceLogDataGrid.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            CoreServiceLogDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(CoreServiceLogDataGrid.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

I have more sample code if needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: -.- And your problem is?

Comment: @DHN I Want the Selected row to be in **Center** of the visible grid area. Normally the row in even on the TOP or on the bottom of the visible grid area.

Comment: O.o - I'm sorry, that I've to tell you, but this is what you want. A goal... A description of a problem is usually a summary of the status quo plus an indications, which part is wrong or where you're running into issues.

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea what im doing but if you use this code you only Need to select your item and the behaviour will scroll to the right Position.

```
public class RadScrollIntoViewBehavior : Behavior<RadGridView>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler<SelectionChangeEventArgs>(AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is RadGridView)
        {
            RadGridView grid = (sender as RadGridView);
            if (grid.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                grid.UpdateLayout();
                grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.SelectedItem, null);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= new EventHandler<SelectionChangeEventArgs>(AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged);
    }
}




<telerik:RadGridView>
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <my3:RadScrollIntoViewBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors> 
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                     <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Name="example"/>
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```